# Replace Image with Background Image on Small Screens

Tags: css, drupal, responsive-design

A site I'm working is in need of a page for an upcoming event that's a bit of a one-off. Most pages have a mast banner image in the template that spans the full width of the page. On most pages this image just shrinks on small screens. However, on this new page it's a requirement that it switch to a different image at a certain width.

Since this site is in Drupal, I'm a bit hesitant to modify the theme for this one temporary page. Ideally, I'd like to be able to set the default image so that it includes the standard region used in the rest of the site.

If I included the image, would it then be appropriate on small screens, when the image needs to switch, to set `display: none;` on the `<img>` and apply a background image to the container `div`? I think this would work but it seems like a bit of a workaround.

Is there a better way around this?

The image region is simply an `<img>` nested in a series of `<divs>`.

Comment: why don't you set the default banner as background image too?

Answer (score 0):

The work around you mention is quiet easy to achieve. In this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s1qa9ff4/1/)** I have just added:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    img {
        opacity:0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
transition: all 0.3s linear;
    }
```

just to make a transition but a simple display none is as valid while you can add the background image to the image container div. (the z-index is to set the image behind whatever content you may have in the div, specially links)